# Calling Matlab from command line gives Caught unexpected exception of unknown type, why?

Tags: matlab, batch-file, command-line-tool

I am trying to run my Matlab from the command line and I am getting a weird error when doing so. I call a script called `test.m` which looks like this

```
%% Housekeeping
clear all;
clc;
%% Update paths
addpath(genpath(pwd));
disp('INFO: OK');
```

I am calling it from command line in Windows via

```
C:\LocalData\Projects>matlab -nosplash -sd 'C:\LocalData\Projects\' -batch "run('test.m')"
```

and as response I get this

> Caught unexpected exception of unknown type.
> INFO: OK

So the script runs because it reaches the command to display `INFO: OK` but I am wondering, what is the error `Caught unexpected exception of unknown type.` referring to?

EDIT: running it with command

```
C:\LocalData\Projects>matlab -nosplash -sd 'C:\LocalData\Projects\' -r "run('test.m')"
```

produces same error in Matlab prompt

[image]

Comment: Could be something in your startup.m file. Try putting an empty startup.m file in the working directory. Also try running an empty script to ensure it is not the script itself that is doing this.